# Jenkins Pipeline sshPublisher: How to get exit code and output of execCommand?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Using [Jenkins Pipeline's sshPublisher plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/) ("publish over ssh"), is it possible to get the **exit code and output of the command ran with `execCommand`** (after artifacts have been transferred over)?

I'm using the plugin as follows:

```
script {
    echo "Sending artifacts to machine at " + remoteDirectory

    // Use of the ssh publisher plugin over SSH
    sshPublisher(
        failOnError: false,
        publishers: [
            sshPublisherDesc(
                configName: "my-drive",
                transfers: [
                    sshTransfer(
                        sourceFiles: mySourceFilesList,
                        remoteDirectory: remoteDirectory,
                        flatten: true,
                        execCommand: commandToExec,
                        execTimeout: 1800000
                    )
                ],
                sshRetry: [
                    retries: 0
                ]
            )
        ]
    )
    // How can I get the output of execCommand?
    // If the exit code was 1, I want to perform some special steps
    // I'd also like to include the output of the command in these steps
}
```

The wiki page [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59507121) says (this is old and from 2011 though):

> STDOUT and STDERR from the command execution are recorded in the
>   Jenkins console.

Comment: the world may never know... :(

Answer (score 3):

It is a "No" (can't be sure, but I tried everything I can).
And now I'm happy with this script

```bash
ssh user@nas01 su -c "/path/to/command1 arg1 arg2"
```

Comment: Same experience, this plugin is up for adoption and has not received an update in several years. I would suggest a new plugin such as https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin